# Azure Synapse - retrieve inserted row identity value

Tags: sql, azure-synapse

We have an ETL job, which would need to insert a row into `Table X`, and then retrieve the `IDENTITY` value for the row inserted into `Table X` for use in later transformations.
`IDENTITY` is used as a surrogate key, eg like [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql-data-warehouse/sql-data-warehouse-tables-identity).

In SQL Server it is possible to use [SCOPE_IDENTITY](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/scope-identity-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) but this is not available in Azure Synapse (formerly Azure SQL Data warehouse).

#### Simple example

```
╔═══════════════╦═══════╗
║ Id (IDENTITY) ║ Value ║
╠═══════════════╬═══════╣
║             1 ║ abc   ║
║             2 ║ def   ║
╚═══════════════╩═══════╝
```

The job will insert value "hij".

```
╔═══════════════╦═══════╗
║ Id (IDENTITY) ║ Value ║
╠═══════════════╬═══════╣
║             1 ║ abc   ║
║             2 ║ def   ║
║             3 ║ hij   ║
╚═══════════════╩═══════╝
```

The job should know the Id value = 3.

Note: doing MAX(Id) would not work, as the IDENTITY column does not guarantee incremental values, and other inserts could go into the table in the meanwhile.

Does anyone have a suggested solution for this?

Comment: The lack of response would indicate to me that this is not feasible in Synapse (SQLDW). I think if you need to know the new identity, you will need to create it (probably as a GUID) rather than rely on the IDENTITY functions.

Comment: Seems so, unfortunately. Thanks for your comment!

Answer (score 1):

As of October 2022, SCOPE_IDENTITY is still not supported in Azure Synapse.

The method suggested in the comments by Joel Cochran seems to be the safest and most legitimate way:

1. create a GUID (`your_guid`) in the application that creates the job
2. insert `your_guid` and other job metadata into your job table
3. `SELECT id FROM job_table WHERE guid = your_guid`

This has been working without errors for more than 2 years thus far.

Answer (score 0):

I found the same "issue" when joining a project in my current job, we currently use a top 1 query ordered by (desc) an inserted datetime column:

```
SELECT TOP 1 identity_col
FROM schema.table
ORDER BY datetime_col DESC
```

I know it is prone to errors, I wanted to use SCOPE_IDENTITY() but this is as good as it gets... maybe.

Comment: This would cause issues if there are multiple jobs that start concurrently. If they both manage to do inserts before fetching the id, then they would both get the same id.